# Add a drawable within a specified "Path" variable in android?

Tags: android, paint

I am drawing a hexagonal path in android app. Now I want to place an image in the drawn path. Below is the code I am using to draw the path.

```
combPath = getHexPath(cellWidth / 2f, cellWidth / 2f, (float) (cellWidth * Math.sqrt(3) / 4));
fillPaint.setColor(cellSet[c][r] ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawPath(combPath, fillPaint);
```

Method getHexPath()

```
private Path getHexPath(float size, float centerX, float centerY) {
    Path path = new Path();

    for (int j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
        double angle = j * Math.PI / 3;
        float x = (float) (centerX + size * Math.cos(angle));
        float y = (float) (centerY + size * Math.sin(angle));
        if (j == 0) {
            path.moveTo(x, y);
        } else {
            path.lineTo(x, y);
        }
    }


    return path;
}
```

Now I have to place an image in the hexagonal path using "path()" variable. How can I achieve it?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(); // retrieve bitmap that you want to draw somehow
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

combPath = getHexPath(cellWidth / 2f, cellWidth / 2f, (float) (cellWidth * Math.sqrt(3) / 4));

canvas.drawPath(combPath, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

**UPDATED**

Here is an example function of how you can do that

```
private Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap original) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(),
            original.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(30, 20);
    path.lineTo(120, 30);
    path.lineTo(110, 120);
    path.lineTo(20, 110);
    path.lineTo(30, 20);

    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(original, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

You just need to place your bitmap, play with width/height and also insert your path. This code worked for me.

Comment: This draws the bitmap in the whole activity not in the specific hexagonal view.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It isn't changed internally, but you have to work with some destination bitmap. Similar code in `onDraw` method however fails.